# Git plugin for Android Studio without any additional external programs

Tags: android-studio, mercurial, bitbucket

With Eclipse I was able to install just [a simple plugin](http://crunchify.com/how-to-configure-bitbucket-git-repository-in-you-eclipse/), that allowed me to use BitBucket with it. Everything I needed was inside Eclipse.
Is there such a plugin for Android Studio too? I still want to use BitBucket for my projects, and I don't want to install any additional programs, like SourceTree, Mercurial, or whatever

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there isn't one. Both the Git and the Mercurial plugin for Android Studio require the installation of the corresponding command-line tool for working with version control (Git or Mercurial).

You don't need to install any additional GUI tools such as SourceTree.